# I am adding LESS and CSS loader together for both the file types. Is this an overhead for webpack?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, less-loader

Here is the webpack.config.js

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            // LESS-CSS Loader
            test: /\.(le|c)ss$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                },
                require.resolve('css-loader'),
                require.resolve('less-loader')
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The css files will also be processed by less loader so will it cause an overhead? 
I just want to know that will the existing approach cause any overhead or it doesn't have any impact on performance.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to apply those loaders for less files only then change your test to `test: /\.less$/,` it still requires both less and css loader for that, then add another loader for css specific only

```
 {
   test: /\.css$/,
   use: require.resolve('css-loader')
 }
```

Comment: I understand that I can split CSS test from it. I just want to know that will the existing approach cause any overhead or it doesn't have any impact on performance

Comment: probably might add a little build time, because it will have to go through less and css loaders despite reading css files only but should expect correct output anyway.